ASP.NET Core - Token Authorization Issue between Microservices Results in 401 Unauthorized
I'm working on a microservices architecture using ASP.NET Core, with two main services: AuthService for authentication and SearchService for handling professional searches.
Users authenticate via AuthService, and I want the SearchService to retrieve user details from AuthService using a JWT token included in the Authorization header.
When I make a GET request to SearchService, it attempts to call AuthService with the token, but I keep receiving a 401 Unauthorized error from AuthService, which logs "No Authorization header found".
Here's the key part of my setup:
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProfessionalSearchController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<ProfessionalSearchController> _logger;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public ProfessionalSearchController(ILogger<ProfessionalSearchController> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet("search")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchProfessionals([FromQuery] string specialisation)
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirst("uid")?.Value;

        if (userId == null)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User ID not found in token");
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        var patient = await GetUserById(userId);

        if (patient == null)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Patient not found");
            return NotFound("Patient not found.");
        }

        // Rest of the code...
    }

    private async Task<User> GetUserById(string userId)
    {
        var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("No token provided.");
            return null;
        }

        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Replace("Bearer ", ""));

        var response = await client.GetAsync($"http://localhost:5203/api/User/{userId}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<User>();
        }

        var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _logger.LogWarning($"Failed to get user by ID {userId}, StatusCode: {response.StatusCode}, Error: {errorContent}");

        return null;
    }
}

I have tried:

Verified that the token includes the necessary claims, including roles
Confirmed that the Authorization header in the SearchService request to AuthService is set as Bearer {token}
Ensured both services share identical token validation parameters (Issuer, Audience, and Signing Key).
Tested the endpoint in Postman by directly calling AuthService, which works fine with the same token

The logs show that AuthService isn't receiving the authorization header from SearchService, leading to the 401 Unauthorized response.
Here is the specific log:
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler: Information: 
Start processing HTTP request GET 
http://localhost:5203/api/User/b4e60ba8-79fa-4c33-a862- 
f60d06213d6b
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler: Information: 
Sending HTTP request GET http://localhost:5203/api/User/b4e60ba8- 
79fa-4c33-a862-f60d06213d6b
BackendDocVillage.Startup: Information: Request Method: GET, Path: 
/api/User/b4e60ba8-79fa-4c33-a862-f60d06213d6b
BackendDocVillage.Startup: Information: Received Token: Bearer 
eyJhbGci..
BackendDocVillage.Startup: Information: Request Method: GET, Path: 
/api/User/b4e60ba8-79fa-4c33-a862-f60d06213d6b
BackendDocVillage.Startup: Information: No Authorization header 
found.
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler: Information: 
Received HTTP response headers after 38.9651ms - 401
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler: Information: 
End processing HTTP request after 52.6424ms - 401
SearchService.Controllers.ProfessionalSearchController: Warning: 
Failed to get user by ID b4e60ba8-79fa-4c33-a862-f60d06213d6b, 
StatusCode: Unauthorized, Error: 
SearchService.Controllers.ProfessionalSearchController: Warning: 
Patient not found

Both services are running locally (AuthService on http://localhost:5203 and SearchService on http://localhost:5095).
AuthService and SearchService are configured to use JWT Bearer authentication.

what httpClient are you using? Is it the default one for C#?. Maybe you can try some alternative http client libraries for .Net

Since it works from Postman it seems to indicate that there's nothing wrong in AuthService when it's correct. Only thing that might be different by default with Postman would be it bypasses CORS. Is the Authorization header being added  when you inspect while debugging? Is it there when you send it when you check what the request looks like before it is sent?

What does the AuthService CORS policy look like?

Are you redirecting to https from the http you're using here at all?

@Tayo I'm using the default HttpClient in .NET, set up through IHttpClientFactory. Here’s a quick outline of my setup:
In Startup.cs, I’ve registered HttpClient using services.AddHttpClient() to handle outbound HTTP requests.
Then, in the controller, I inject IHttpClientFactory to create a new instance of HttpClient for each request.

@EricBelisleGiddings elow is the CORS policy currently in use. I’ve configured it to allow any origin, method, and header, and exposed the Authorization header explicitly: services.AddCors(options => {     options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder =>     {         builder.AllowAnyOrigin()                .AllowAnyMethod()                .AllowAnyHeader()                .WithExposedHeaders("Authorization");     }); });     Yes, HTTPS redirection is enabled app.UseHttpsRedirection();

I forgot the was machine to machine so CORS shouldn't matter here either.
Have you tried examining if the header is being sent? Like put a breakpoint on the request or log it to ensure that the request has the Authorization header?
Do you have any sort of custom configuration on the HttpClient?
Can you try setting the token directly as one you know that works to rule out the token.Replace method?
Is there any sort of proxy or middleware in either API that could be stripping it?
Try using Fiddler or Wireshark to see if there's something happening between the servers?

If you can get the request details from the API and the request details from Postman you can try to diff them if they have the same format. That might also lead to some insight.
